# mongoose.connect is not a function

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, import, importerror

When i use Mongoose and try to connect via the connect('connect-string') method i get the error TypeError: connect is not a function below is the code i use

```
import { connect } from 'mongoose'
import { userModel } from './models/User'

const auth = await connect("connect-string")

export async function createUser(username:String, password:String) {
    try {
        const result = await userModel.create({
            username: username,
            password: password
        })
        console.log(result)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I tried following imports:
import mongoose from 'mongoose'
import { connect } from 'mongoose'

and i reinstalled the npm package